# Is there a C++ function to suspend of resume a child process?

Tags: c++, multithreading, powershell, shell, process

Is there a way to suspend and resume a process using C++? Today, I created a mini shell that will stop some background processes to execute a new foreground process.
Thanks,

Comment: Not in standard C++, you have to use system library.

Answer (score 1):

No. The C++ language is entirely agnostic of the concept of processes and thus also of child processes, and thus doesn't have any functions<sup>1</sup> to directly interact with processes.

<sup>1</sup> With the exception of `std::system` inherited from the C standard library which passes a string to a command processor of the host system in an implementation defined manner, and which is in practice typically implemented by creating a subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

You said Powershell in the tags so I assume Windows.

If you have a handle to a process then you can do things to that process. The list of things you can do is documented in MSDN. In this case you would need to get handles to the individual threads in a process so you can suspend the threads: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/suspending-thread-execution

Doing this in POSIX is a bit easier. You just need to send a SIGSTOP signal to the target process. Then it and all its threads will stop running until you send SIGCONT.